# Unable to set min and max instance number to 0 in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't set the EC2 instance number in the application load balancer of my elastic beanstalk environment to 0.

EB tells me `Max must be between 0 and 10000.`.

Why does this happen?

[image]

I've followed [this article](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=141982) and set my `Deployment policy` as `All at once` and `Rolling update type` as `Disabled`.

[image]

But the problem still exists.

Setting `Deployment policy` as `Rolling` and `Rolling update type` as `Disabled` doesn't work, either.

Is there any other factor that affects the values of min and max instance number?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't let you set the maximum to 0, but you can definitely set the min/max to 0 through a Time-based scaling action at the bottom of the Capacity configuration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This phenomenon automatically disappears after a few days. Probably it's a bug of AWS.